# jQuery-JS appending from multidimensional arrays with loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

apparently I can't understand how JS's logic works when parsing data from multidimensional arrays.

let's say we have a 3D array as this:

```
 var data = new Array(("1","2",("7","8","9")),("3","4",("10","11","12")),("5","6",("13","14","15")));
```

and I have a simple HTML structure to start with like a single div with id=parentdiv

and i want to append it in the DOM in order to look like every dimension is in a different div but still child to the div of the previous dimention ending up in something like:
childdiv1:( 
1 
2 
grandchilddiv1.1: 
7 
grandchilddiv1.2: 
8 
grandchilddiv1.3: 
9) 
childdiv2:( 
3 
4 
grandchilddiv2.1: 
10 
grandchilddiv2.2: 
11 
grandchilddiv2.3: 
12) 
childdiv3:( 
5 
6 
grandchilddiv3.1: 
13 
grandchilddiv3.2: 
14 
grandchilddiv3.3: 
15) 
ending up printing a simple 1 2 7 8 9 3 4 10 11 12 5 6 13 14 15

setting up a fiddle to check how loops work.. http://jsfiddle.net/M_Elf/68zfgdaq/1/
Using $each instead of for ofcourse doesn't change anything
what I noticed is that each loop is acting like independently from its parent loops... Never seen examples parsing data from more than 2 dimensions and a loop inside a loop doesn't seem to work as I predicted... Any suggestions?

---

solved with recursion way of thinking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're using the `Array()` constructor properly. It's a bit unconventional to use that constructor rather than just `var arr = [1, 2, 3];`

The problem is that the `Array()` constructor expects each argument to be a single value or object; instead you're trying to feed it multidimensional arrays, but you aren't constructing those inner arrays properly! It should probably look something like this:

```
var data = new Array(new Array(1, 2, 3), new Array(4, 5, 6), new Array(7, 8, 9));
```

An easier and more intuitive way to do it would be to just declare the array like this:

```
var data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
```

It makes it easier to see how the arrays nest and what the multidimensional structure is.

Comment: by transforming the array into a form like` "var data = [[1, 2, [7, 8, 9]], [3, 4, [10, 11, 12]], [5, 6, [13, 14, 15]]];" `  then I guess the syntax should also change? JQuery says there are "parameter is not of type 'Node'" errors

Comment: This is a classic recursion problem. Take a gander at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/belross/h54u2w58/

Comment: recursion! exactly what i needed!

Comment: what if i wanted to put elements 7 8 9, 10 11 12 and 13 14 15 in 3 separate lists? inside a parent div?

Comment: @CookieMonster I'm not sure what you mean, but if you restructure the array you can achieve any nested order of elements that you want.